# Positioning of Text with Images HTML

Tags: css, html, styling

I have a small problem here.  I have a Div and I would like the text to float either side in the centre.

I include a screenshot of it presently and how I would like it to look does anyone have any idea if this is achievable or do I need to make it an actual image?

[image: Twitter Facebook Feeds]

JS Fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/DU4u4/

Comment: please post your code , `jsfiddle` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `vertical-align: middle`

Answer (score 2):

..........................................

Now used to `line-height` for this

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this is something you need...

Check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/pxFWA/19/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="socialConnect">
    <div class="fbConnect">Follow us on</div>
    <div class="twitterConnect">OR</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fbConnect{
    background-image:url('http://www.seedaneed.com/images/fb_btn.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    height:32px;
    width:125px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.twitterConnect{
    background-image:url('http://www.boson.com/images/twitter-button.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    height:32px;
    width:60px;    
    float:left;    
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    text-align:left;
}
```